# How to dynamically update a partial view upon button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

First is i have 2 database tables.
1st table is for items and 2nd table is for processes per item.

The first table data will be displayed as an html table and each row
will have an edit, delete, show process button/link which will be generated dynamically.

My problem is i want to show the 2nd table as a partial view at the bottom of the first table(the same view) upon choosing an item by clicking the button or link(processes).

The partial view will update dynamically when new item is selected.

My first view is using IEnumerable library, should my partial view use an IEnumerable library also?

I tried to load my partial view using javascript but 'm getting an error.

Comment: Show what you have tried and the details of the error.

Comment: dude, you should consider any front-end framework for this kind of projects. I recommend you AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an action which will accept parameter and return your partial view. On your client-side place a div for second table and register click handlers:

```
<div>
    <button id="btnLoadTable">Load table with id = 1</button>
</div>
<div id="table2">TABLE 2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btnLoadTable').click(function(){
                $('#table2').load('yoursite.com/controller/partialViewAction');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Jquery `$.load` function performs http request, receives `html` of your partial view and places it into `<div id="table2">`